# Arrays and integers in c

Tags: c, assignment-operator

In this example I want to print out the number `4`. This is a simplified version of my problem, but my issue is the same. After assigning `b` a value (in this case `4`), I want to print out the 4th element of the array, not directly, but by using a separate integer (c). However a `0` gets printed out as a result. I have no idea why. Would be glad if you could help. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numbers[10], a, b, c;

int main() {
    for (a = 0; a < 11; a++) {
        numbers[a] = a;
    }
    b = 7 - 3;
    numbers[b] = c;
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using (reading) `c` before initializing (writing) it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I cannot believe how I was so dumb! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the 4th element of the array, you should read it and store it into `c`:

```
c = numbers[b];
```

Also note that the initialization loop runs one step too far, assigning non-existent element `numbers[10]`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numbers[10], a, b, c;

    for (a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        numbers[a] = a;
    }
    b = 7 - 3;
    c = numbers[b];
    printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```